# Creating a Directory Through shell script and retrieve the path

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

I am trying to create a directory through shell script. Through some commands I am able to create a directory with permission string 777. Now I want to fetch the path of the created directory so that I can move a file into that.

Below is the code though which I am trying.

It will store datetime

`NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")`

It will store hostname

`HOST=$(hostname -s)`

Create directory with permission

`LOG_DIRECTORY=$(mkdir -m 777 DIP_${HOST}_${NOW}_50users)`

To fetch path

`path="$(dirname /home/e250842/${LOG_DIRECTORY})";`

And display path

`echo "$path"`

But the problem is that `LOG_DIRECTORY` is not a path.So please suggest some command to fetch the path like `/home/e250842/CreatedDirectoryName/`.

An example is also helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you format your code?  It is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code

```
LOG_DIRECTORY=$(mkdir -m 777 DIP_${HOST}_${NOW}_50users)
path="$(dirname /home/e250842/${LOG_DIRECTORY})"
```

to

```
LOG_DIRECTORY="DIP_${HOST}_${NOW}_50users"
mkdir -m 777 "${LOG_DIRECTORY}"
path="/home/e250842/${LOG_DIRECTORY}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
host=$(hostname -s)
path=$(pwd)/DIP_${host}_${now}_50users
mkdir -m 777 "$path"
echo "$path" -- display path
```